# Changing Filestore configuration from full-db to file-system

Tags: database, binary, filesystems, artifactory

Right now I'm running Artifactory 5.1.4 with the following binarystore.xml contents:

```
<config version="1">
   <chain>
      <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
         <provider id="retry" type="retry">
            <provider id="blob" type="blob"/>
         </provider>
      </provider>
   </chain>

   <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
      <cacheProviderDir>/data/cache</cacheProviderDir>
      <maxCacheSize>50000000000</maxCacheSize>
   </provider>
</config>
```

Is there a possibility to stop using my database to store binaries and switch to file-system usage in the same server?

What I could imagine, would be to export all repositories, change the binary store.xml to:

```
<config version="1">
   <chain>
      <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
         <provider id="file-system" type="file-system"/>
      </provider>
   </chain>

   <provider id="cache-fs" type="cache-fs">
      <cacheProviderDir>/data/cache</cacheProviderDir>
      <maxCacheSize>50000000000</maxCacheSize>
   </provider>

   <provider id="file-system" type="file-system">
      <fileStoreDir>/data/repos</fileStoreDir>
   </provider>
</config>
```

Restart Artifactory and Import repositories again.

Is this the correct procedure?
Finally, how could I scrub the database and remove all binaries afterwards? Is there a specific query for that?

Thank you all in advance for any help/direction!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, the process should look like the following:

1. Run  full system export
2. Shutdown Artifactory
3. [Create DB new schema](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Database#ConfiguringtheDatabase-SetuptheNewDatabase) to store your metadata
4. Configure both -

   1. The filestore for your binaries under the binarystore.xml file
   2. The new DB scheme under db.properties file **and also remove the fulldb parameter.**
5. Start Artifactory
6. Run a full system import from the export you performed
7. Drop the previous DB schema

Just to emphasise that Artifactory uses its DB to store metadata, that could also store your binaries otherwise you’d like to store them in a separate filestore.